# A regex I have working in Ruby doesn't in PHP; what could the cause be?

Tags: php, ruby, regex

I do not know ruby.  I am trying to use the following regex that was generated by ruby (namely by http://www.a-k-r.org/abnf/ running on the grammar given rfc1738) in php.  It is failing to match in php, but it is successfully matching in ruby.  Does anyone see what differences between php's and ruby's handling of regexes that might explain this discrepancy?

```
http:\/\/(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-z]|[0-9a-z](?:[\x2d0-9a-z]?)*[0-9a-z])\x2e)?)*(?:[a-z]|[a-z](?:[\x2d0-9a-z]?)*[0-9a-z])|\d+\x2e\d+\x2e\d+\x2e\d+)(?::\d+)?(?:\/(?:(?:[!\x24'-\x2e0-9_a-z]|%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[&:;=@])?)*(?:(?:\/(?:(?:[!\x24'-\x2e0-9_a-z]|%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[&:;=@])?)*)?)*(?:\x3f(?:(?:[!\x24'-\x2e0-9_a-z]|%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[&:;=@])?)*)?)?/i
```

Since you all *love* regexes so much, how about an alternate solution.
Given the ABNF in an rfc, I want a way (in php) to check if an arbitrary string is in the grammar.

[APG](http://www.coasttocoastresearch.com/) fails to compile on a 64-bit system,

[VTC](http://www.vinegen.com/en/textcompiler.html) is not *F*ree,

and I have not found any other such tools.  I would also prefer not to use a regex, but it's the closest I've come to success.

Comment: You'll want to post a code sample showing how you invoke the reg-ex in Ruby vs. how you invoke it in PHP.  Most PHP reg-ex problems boil down to string escaping.  i.e. in PHP  you pass a string to the pcre functions.  The string has escaping applied before it goes to the reg-ex engine, meaning the reg-ex you think you're passing often isn't the actual one.  (there's also the problem of PCRE (preg_) vs. (ereg_).  You probably want preg.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know,
I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.

Comment: The only thing worse than a human at generating regexes, is a computer.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a regular expression, can only think to quote another developer's snark.

Comment: Calling it in ruby, I'm saving the generated regex as re and then running
pp 'http://us2.php.net/' =~ re
which as I understand gives me a non-nil value on a match.
In php, I copied the printed regex and saved it in a file.

I then open the file, read the regex from the file using fgets (I'd assume this does all the escaping necessary... or at leasts avoids the necessity), saving it in $re, then run
echo preg_match($re, 'http://us2.php.net/');

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to see a sample of the code you were trying to use in PHP, but try the following (remember to change $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] to your input variable):

```
if (preg_match('#http://(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-z]|[0-9a-z](?:[\\x2d0-9a-z]?)*[0-9a-z])\\x2e)?)*(?:[a-z]|[a-z](?:[\\x2d0-9a-z]?)*[0-9a-z])|\\d+\\x2e\\d+\\x2e\\d+\\x2e\\d+)(?::\\d+)?(?:/(?:(?:[!\\x24\'-\\x2e0-9_a-z]|%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[&:;=@])?)*(?:(?:/(?:(?:[!\\x24\'-\\x2e0-9_a-z]|%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[&:;=@])?)*)?)*(?:\\x3f(?:(?:[!\\x24\'-\\x2e0-9_a-z]|%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[&:;=@])?)*)?)?#i', $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], $l_Results)) {
    $result = $l_Results[1];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this produces no result with $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] equal to 'http://us2.php.net/'.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to - your regex requires http:// at the beginning.  Perhaps you could explain better what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: test of autolinking in comments; i have the http written this time: http://us2.php.net/

Comment: Are you simply trying to identify a URI link inside of your input text?  If so, your regex is incorrect and you should be using: \b(https?|ftp|file)://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]